# JMeter Thread-Group with separate jks file

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jks

I'm trying to simulate a scenario where each thread-group are using their separate jks certificate to mutually authenticate self with server. My simplified implementation is like this :

Thread-Group 1: 1 User, Loop 1

Thread-Group 2: 1 User, Loop 1

And I have configured Certificate by options->ssl-manager.
What I want is to configure :

Thread-Group 1: 1 User, Loop 1 , jks1

Thread-Group 2: 1 User, Loop 1 ,jks2

I found something [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BbjyAgPT_TkJ:www.jmeter-archive.org/Single-SSL-Certificate-per-Thread-td5727136.html%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=ubuntu) but couldn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

As of JMeter 5.4.1 you can only use one JKS keystore for holding the client certificates, for non-GUI test execution you can specify the path to the keystore using [`javax.net.ssl.keyStore` system property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration).

However the keystore can have more than one certificate and you have freedom to choose which one you want to use using [aliases](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123944/what-is-the-purpose-role-of-the-alias-attribute-in-java-keystore-files)

See [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article for more details if needed.